# how do i time a c function to execute for x seconds only

Tags: timer, counter

a function expecting user input disables all interrupts at the prompt and i'm trying to get the function to run for 10 seconds then exit or refresh.
I'm using c in avr studio 5

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
sleep(10);
```

It is relatively accurate.  For more accuracy, use:

```
usleep().
```

Both are in:

```
#include <unistd.h>
```

I'm not exactly sure what you want to do:

```
while(t<50){
    Lock();
    t++;
}
sleep(100);
/* end of routine.... */
```

Comment: thanks, but am using avr-gcc and doesnt contain that header file, instead avr/sleep.h .I want the function to run for 10 seconds then completely exit the loop

Comment: here's what i have but doesn't work.  `while(t<50)
{     
Lock();
sleep(100);}`

Comment: To exit a loop, you need a break (or at least increment the variable being checked with the conditional).  I'm not sure exactly what you want to do.

Comment: the condition t is a value from a sensor and Lock() is a function that waits for user input.if t increments while lock is being executed, it doesn't interrupt Lock()... as it should, thus i need to let Lock() execute for 10 seconds then re-evaluate condition t, or break after the 10 seconds.

Comment: Hmm, I don't think you can break a lock.  It's blocked to wait for user input.  If you want to do what you say, instead of lock you need some kind of polling to determine if the user input something.  How is the user input accessed?  [I can see your problem now, you want a Lock() to break and it isn't doing it for you....]

Comment: user enters input from buttons and i've tried polling to determine if a user has pressed a key by using   <br/>  `{
   
uint8_t keypressed;
keypressed=GetKeyPressed();
Wait(3);
if (keypressed=0xff)
{
LCDClear();
goto START;
}
Lock();
}`

Comment: and while polling for a key pressed, are interrupts active such that an increment or decrement of t will cause it to re-evaluate the condition? seems like it gets stuck waiting for a key to be pressed, just like what we trying to solve in the lock() function.

Comment: solved by using a different mcu to monitor sensor interrupts... although such an inneficient use of resources :-(